# ItemWebService not working

Tags: sitecore-api

So I need to retrieve an item using the sitecore API. So firstly, I need to log in, Im following what this site states:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice

But then again, Im getting a 401 unauthorized error with the right credentials (I tested it loggin in the browser). There it says that  loggin in only responds over HTTPS. How can I access an item using the sitecore API if I the sitecore web site doesnt use Https ?

Sitecore 8

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: Sitecore 8 @RichardSeal

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your site needs to be secured.  There's no way to override the HTTPS requirement unless you override the /ssc/auth route and use your own login mechanism.

**NOTE: I don't recommend below but if you MUST really not have HTTPS...**

You can do this by updating the `Sitecore.Services.RouteMapper` setting in the `Sitecore.Services.Client.config`.  Reflect the `DefaultMapper` and override the `MapRoutes` method that defines the "auth" route.  You'll notice that it's pointing to `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Mvc.ServicesAuthenticationController`.  So, you'll need to copy that and essentially remove the `"RequireHttps"` attribute on the `Login` method.  Point your new auth route to this new controller.

With regards to more details on the SSC, you may want to check the [7.5 documentation](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf) as it has a lot more examples.  Most of it still applies.

Comment: This is the solution I needed. I agree that in most circumstances this should never be done, however for dev environments or production environments where SSL is offloaded (e.g. behind a load balancer or downstream web server which provides the SSL) then this is an absolute must. Sitecore themselves have even introduced a setting `Sitecore.Services.AllowToLoginWithHttp` to disable the https requirement in the most recent version 9.3

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/sitecore-services-client-security.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do this on your local machine for dev purposes (e.g self signed cert in IIS) then you can do the following to work-around the SSL validation:

```
requestUrl = $"https://{_baseAPIUrl}/sitecore/api/ssc/auth"
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(requestUrl);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";

//ignore ssl cert validation - enabled for local dev only
if (_skipSslCertValidation)
    request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

However *Please Do Not* use this in any other environments as it will open up a security hole with invalid certs.  Chrome and Firefox now mark websites as insecure if they don't run under SSL. Therefore you should use SSL in all environments where possible now anyway.