# Sitecore Item Web API returning "Https is required"

Tags: item-web-api

Have tried a bunch of things, including this: [ItemWebService not working](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/itemwebservice-not-working)

Have also tried these settings as well:

```
<setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" set:value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" set:role="ContentManagement" />
<setting name="Sitecore.Services.AllowToLoginWithHttp" set:value="true" set:role="ContentManagement" />
<setting name="Sitecore.Services.AllowAnonymousUser" set:value="true" />
```

No luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

this was happening because our infrastructure did not have end to end SSL configured. Traffic between our load balancer and the web servers were in HTTP. None of the above settings helped with that.

We had to turn on end-to-end SSL and this started working.