# Sitecore 10 item api returns https only error when authorizing

Tags: sitecore-rocks, item-web-api, kubernetes

We have a sitecore instance running on K8's, the traffic between our ingress controller and CM is http - and we're getting an `https only` error in both Sitecore Rocks and the sitecore item api.

My understanding is it's not common practice to implement https from ingress to pods, so this must be a common issue? I'm hoping for a simpler workaround via config or something.

It appears this was asked [over a year ago](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29858/sitecore-item-web-api-returning-https-is-required) and nobody had a solution... Has there been any change recently?

Comment: Rather than open a duplicate question, you should consider putting a bounty on the original question to get some traction. Or even adding comments will bump the activity level of the question up.

Comment: There are some more details here too: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/itemwebservice-not-working

Comment: Thanks that link has what I'm after!